# Saving files to Blob Storage

Tags: json, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-automation

I am running an API call using PowerShell via Azure Automation and I wanted to save the JSON files directly into a Blob Storage without having to save anything to the local machine first and then transfer the JSON files into Blob Storage as this process will be used by others. Is saving JSON files directly to Blob Storage possible without hitting the local machine? I am happy to change my approach to achieve to save JSON files directly into Blob Storage.

UPDATED API Code

```
$access_token ="Access_Token"
$URI =  "https://XXXXX"
$headers = @{“authorization” = “Bearer $access_token”} 
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Headers $headers -ContentType $ContentType |ConvertTo-Json
$Result|ConvertFrom-Json| Select -ExpandProperty Forms
```

RESULT:

```
{
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "options": [
                    "New York Bulls",
                    "Los Angeles Kings",
                    "Golden State Warriros",
                    "Huston Rocket"
                ],
                "answer": "Huston Rocket"
            }
        },
        "maths": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "10",
                    "11",
                    "12",
                    "13"
                ],
                "answer": "12"
            },
            "q2": {
                "question": "12 - 8 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4"
                ],
                "answer": "4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From where do you want to save your json file? From a Pipeline Task? Or from a local machine?

Comment: Into Blob Storage not local machine. Don't want to use local machine at all

Comment: There is a possibility to store json/files indirectly in blob storage over extension documents. I describe how it work in powershell in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49329682/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-document-collections-in-a-given-tfs-web-extension/57625326#57625326). Maybe it help with you problem? but in this case you need a extension.

Comment: @Djbril,  hello, can you solve your issue now?

Comment: @Ivan Yang. I have updated my question with my API code. Where would I put my API Code within your solution?

Comment: @Djbril, can you confirm what's the result of your last code($Result|ConvertFrom-Json| Select -ExpandProperty Forms)? if it's a json string, then you can do something like this: $myjson = $Result|ConvertFrom-Json| Select -ExpandProperty Forms. Then in my solution, just put the $myjson into this method $myblob.UploadText, like $myblob.UploadText($myjson).

Comment: @Djbril, please contact me if you still have issues about that.

Comment: @Ivan Yang. I have added the result of the API in the original question.

Comment: @Djbril, can you solve your issue now?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we can export the json file directly to Blob Storage, we have to use the middle bridge (staging storage) to pass the file to Blob storage. Refer to 
[Quickstart: Upload, download, and list blobs by using Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell) for details.

If you mean in Azure DevOps pipeline, then you can export the json file to a staging folder in the agent, then use the [Azure File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops) to upload the file to Blog storage.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using azure blob storage sdk in runbook.

**First**, you need to import the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll` in azure blob storage sdk as module in the runbook. Follow the steps below:

1.Get the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll`. If you don't know how to get it, just open the visual studio -> create a .net framework console project -> then right click the console project -> Manage Nuget Packages, then search and download the azure blob storage sdk [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/)

2.When the package installed, build the console project, then in the bin -> debug folder, you can see `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll`.

3.Put the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll` into a zip file named `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.zip`

4.Go to azure portal -> your automation account -> in the left pane, click "Modules" -> Add a module -> select the .zip file in step 2. You need wait for a few minutes for the module completes uploading(when it completes uploading, you can find the status of **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage module** is **Available** ), see the screenshot below:

[image]

**Secondly**, create a powershell runbook, and write the code like below. Here, I just upload a string using `UploadText("your_string_text")` method. **Note that** since the sdk provides many upload method, you should check the return value from the api is text / stream / byte format, then select the proper upload method like `UploadFromStream(your_stream)` / `UploadFromByteArray(byte[] buffer, int index, int count)`:

```
Write-Output "start the test"

Add-Type -Path "C:\Modules\User\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll"

$access_token ="Access_Token"
$URI =  "https://XXXXX"
$headers = @{“authorization” = “Bearer $access_token”} 
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 
[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Headers $headers -ContentType $ContentType |ConvertTo-Json
$blob_content_to_upload = $Result|ConvertFrom-Json| Select -ExpandProperty Forms

$account_name = "xxx"
$account_key = "xxx"
$container_name = "test1"
$blob_name = "testfile3.txt"

Write-Output "start communicate with blob storage"

$creds = New-Object "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials" -ArgumentList $account_name,$account_key

$storageAccount = New-Object "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount" -ArgumentList $creds,$true
$cloudBlobClient = $storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
$cloudBlobContainer = $cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference($container_name)
$myblob = $cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference($blob_name)

#note that the sdk also provides other methods like UploadFromStream(your_stream) / UploadFromByteArray(byte[] buffer, int index, int count), you can choose the proper method for your purpose.
$myblob.UploadText($blob_content_to_upload)

Write-Output("***the test is completed***")
```

Then you can run the runbook, after it completes, you can see the blob is created on blob storage with proper content. Note that during the running, there maybe a error says the modules loading issue, but it doesn't matter.

The test result, blob is created on blob storage.

[image]

If you want to specify the content-type, just add this line of code: `$myblob.Properties.ContentType = "your_content_type"`